# Application Insights - Unable to view SQL Query

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have hosted an ASP.NET MVC application and configured Application Insight.
All HTTP calls and SQL dependencies are logged in a text file.
But, I am unable to log/get the SQL queries via Application Insight "commandName" parameter.

Can someone help me on this, please.

1. Application Insight without Azure account.
2. To get the SQL queries, do I need to install any profilers ?

Answer (score 3):

If your application is hosted on Azure Web Apps, install Application Insights Extension.
If hosted on any other VM, install Status Monitor on  that VM. Then restart the application, and you should start seeing full SQL queries in Dependency command.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now

Comment: HI Thomas, thanks for your answer. Is there a way to log the SQL dependency in a text file before it sends to Azure?

Comment: Can you describe the scenario a bit more? In general, you can write a TextWriterTelemetryProcessory and write the telemetry to a file if you want..

Comment: I have a web application with Application Insights added. I want to log the SQL dependency in a text file. How to achieve this?